# R How do save xts plots using lapply

Tags: r, plot, lapply, xts

I am working with some parliamentary text copra and I'm trying to visualize some of the results. Since I got a list of items I am trying to use a lapply to iterate through my list.

```
    keywords <- c("inburgering", 
             "inburgeringscursus", 
             "inburgeringsplicht", 
             "kennismigranten", 
             "gezinshereniging", 
             "gezinsvorming", 
             "Vreemdelingenwet")}
```

While outputting barplots works just fine

```
lapply(keywords, function(keyword){
  dt <- dispersion(corpus_in_use, query = keyword, sAttribute = "date")
  ts <- xts(x = dt[,count],
          order.by = as.Date(sprintf("%s-01-01", dt[["date"]])))
  ts_qtr <- aggregate(ts, as.Date(sprintf("%s-01-01", gsub("^(\\d{4})-.*?$", "\\1", index(ts)))))

  jpeg(
    filename = paste("/Users/simgeh/Downloads/bar_", keyword, ".jpg", sep=""),
    width = 2000, height = 1200,
    res = NA
  )

  barplot(ts_qtr, main=keyword, lwd=1, las=3)
  dev.off()
})
```

visualizing lineplots using `plot` won't work. I got no error. Just `null device 1`.

```
lapply(keywords, function(keyword){
  disp <- dispersion(corpus_in_use, query = keyword, sAttribute = c("date", "party"))
  ts <- xts(x = disp[,c("CDA", "PVV", "VVD", "PvdA", "D66", "GL")],
            order.by = as.Date(sprintf("%s-01-01", disp[["date"]])))

  #ts_adj <- aggregate(ts, as.Date(sprintf("%s-01-01", gsub("^(\\d{4})-.*?$", "\\1", index(ts)))))
  ts_adj <- as.xts(aggregate(ts, as.Date(as.yearmon(index(ts)))))

  jpeg(
    filename = paste("/Users/simgeh/Downloads/", keyword, ".jpg", sep=""),
    width = 4000, height = 2400,
    res = NA
  )

  plot(ts_adj, 
       main=keyword, 
       multi.panel = TRUE, 
       col = c("black", "black", "blue", "green", "red", "yellow"), 
       lwd=6, 
       cex = 1.5, 
       las = 1)
  dev.off()
})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it seems like everything worked as expected, maybe something is wrong in the path you provided. What do you get if you try to plot one of the keywords directly in the session?

Comment: @Cath I concur, I did not read the question thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. You have to set it in print:

```
print(plot(ts_adj, 
       main=keyword, 
       multi.panel = TRUE, 
       col = c("black", "black", "blue", "green", "red", "yellow"), 
       lwd=6, 
       cex = 1.5, 
       las = 1))
  dev.off()
```